# Using ODP.NET for Oracle 12.2c with IPC connections: NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle12c, odp.net, odac

After installing Oracle 12c Release 2, I am running into some problems with database and transaction handling. The version of the `ODP.NET` dll (`Oracle.DataAccess.dll`) is 4.122.1.0, and I am using a PC with Windows 7 Professional.

I am no longer able to use the `OracleConnection.State` property to monitor the state of a connection, which breaks existing code.
It seems that simply accessing the State property corrupts the `OracleConnection` object, but only when using `IPC` connections. Below is a code example that reproduces the problem. The database in this example is run on my local system.

```
private const string ConnectionStringIPC = @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(Key = EXTPROC1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = GLOBAL)));User Id=TestCase;Password=TestCase;Validate Connection=true;";
private const string ConnectionStringTCP = @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = GLOBAL)));User Id=TestCase;Password=TestCase;Validate Connection=true;";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IPC:");
    TestCase1(ConnectionStringIPC);
    TestCase2(ConnectionStringIPC);

    Console.WriteLine("TCP:");
    TestCase1(ConnectionStringTCP);
    TestCase2(ConnectionStringTCP);
}

private static void TestCase1(string connectionString)
{
    try
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

        Console.WriteLine("TestCase1 succesful!");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestCase1 failed:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
}

private static void TestCase2(string connectionString)
{
    try
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        var state = conn.State;
        OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

        Console.WriteLine("TestCase2 succesful!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestCase2 failed:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

The output of this program is

```
IPC:
TestCase1 succesful!  
TestCase2 failed:  
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.get_TxnHndAllocated()  
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.BeginTransaction()  
   at OracleConnectionTest.Program.TestCase2(String connectionString)  
TCP:  
TestCase1 succesful!  
TestCase2 succesful!
```

As you can see, simply accessing the `OracleConnection.State` property is enough to invalidate the object, triggering an exception in the subsequent `OracleTransaction.BeginTransaction` call.

Is there anything wrong with the way I try to use the `OracleConnection` and `OracleTransaction` objects?
If not, is this a known bug, and is there any good work-around?